# Converting a jRuby script into a Groovy script

Tags: ruby, groovy, jruby

I've been trying to convert this ruby bootstrap to groovy for someone and so far i'm a bit confused as i'm still a beginner in ruby.

This is basically a plugin system. The bootstrap ruby script allows me to create multiple scripts for my server with hooks onto the button handler so I can handle button clicking inside a ruby script instead. An example of the plugin script is this:

Now i'm trying to do it for Groovy but i don't know how to call the extra parameters[player,slot,param] and handle it like in the example plugin script above

Thanks, i hope u guys understand my problem but i'll provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Ruby guru, but AFAIK, `Proc` is similar to Groovy's `Closure`, so my guess it'd be something like:

```
class ProcButtonHandler extends ButtonHook {
  Closure proc
  ProcButtonHandler(id, proc) {
    super(id)
    this.proc = proc
  }

  void handle(player, slot, parameter) {
    proc player, slot, parameter
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha thanks the closure was what lead me to the right direction :) Thanks